# How do I test a localhost url in nightwatch js

Tags: selenium, webdriver, nightwatch.js

I am trying to run UI regression tests against a local project. 
I am running the project with Browsersync, which ends up at localhost:3000.

I have tried setting the url to the directory of my distributed files but this also does not work. Internet Explorer opens but cannot connect to the page.

Here is my nightwatch.json

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["nightwatch/tests"],
  "output_folder" : "nightwatch/reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "nightwatch/commands",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "nightwatch/assertions",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "start_session" : true,
    "server_path" : "C:\\Selenium\\selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : "C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe"
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {

    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "on_failure" : false,
        "on_error" : false,
        "path" : "test/screenshots/"
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "internet explorer",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },

    "chrome" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my test

```
    module.exports = {
        before : function (browser) {
            browser.resizeWindow(1024, 800);
        },
        'OOBE Homepage': function(browser) {
            browser
            .url('http://localhost:3000/index.html')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 5000)
            .compareScreenshot('desktop-index.png')
            .end();
        },
};
```

Comment: Have you tried any web URL like google.com, is it working? There should not be problem opening only localhost URL, working like charm at my end.

Comment: Shouldn't your "launch_url": "http://localhost" be set to "http://localhost:3000" or "http://localhost:3000/index.html" as per your start url in the test?

Comment: Yes, changing to the launch url to localhost:3000 worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the launch_url to localhost:3000 worked.

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["nightwatch/tests"],
  "output_folder" : "nightwatch/reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "nightwatch/commands",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "nightwatch/assertions",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "start_session" : true,
    "server_path" : "C:\\Selenium\\selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : "C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe"
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {

    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost:3000",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "on_failure" : false,
        "on_error" : false,
        "path" : "test/screenshots/"
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "internet explorer",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },

    "chrome" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```